# Crystal Reports with Java

Tags: java, crystal-reports, xlsx

I am using Java to generate crystal reports locally -not on report application server- and trying to export to XLSX format.
but so far, I was only able to export to xls format.

does the java library for crystal reports support xlsx format?

`Edit 2018-02-02`

if possible, I want the file to be saved directly as XLSX.
I found some suggestions on SAP forums saying that you can open it in xls and then save as xlsx.

but the problem is that my report has too many rows and exceeds the sheet limit, so crystal report will create a new sheet every time the row count exceeds the limit.

if I were to save in xls and then open and save as xlsx, then I will have to merge the sheets and I am not sure of the impact this will have on formatting.

`update 2018-02-15:`

I was able to export directly to xlsx using the JAR files provided on the crystal reports web site: [Crystal reports SAP](http://www.crystalreports.com/crviewer-confirm/) , after downloading the crystal report viewer, I added some jars in the folders under: ..\Crystal Reports Viewer\SAP Crystal Reports viewer\plugins and using those jars I was able to export with:

```
    DataOnlyExcelExportFormatOptions options = new 
    DataOnlyExcelExportFormatOptions();
    options.setMaintainColumnAlignment(true);
    options.setSimplifyPageHeaders(false);
    options.setExportPageHeaderAndFooter(true);
    options.setUseWorksheetFunctionsForSummaries(true);
    options.setBaseAreaType(AreaSectionKind.detail);
    ExportOptions exportOpt = new ExportOptions();
    exportOpt.setFormatOptions(options);
    exportOpt.setExportFormatType(ReportExportFormat.recordToMSExcel2007);
    ...
    ReportClientDocument doc1 = ReportClientDocument.openReport(f);
    ...
    PrintOutputController printer = doc1.getPrintOutputController();
    printer.export(exportOpt, fileOutputStream);
```

line of concern here is: ReportExportFormat.recordToMSExcel2007

this will export directly to xlsx.

Comment: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1735662

Comment: `com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.exportoptions.ReportExportFormat` class does not have recordToMSExcel2007 field in newest SDK. I checked SP 29 version 12.2.230.4777. This class is in CrystalReportsRuntime.jar. What version do you use? Do you know how export report to XLSX format using newest Crystal Reports for Eclipse Runtime Libraries?